# Post request with threading

Tags: python, multithreading

Here is my snippet:

```
urls = ["http://goggle.com", "http://linux.com"]
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
data= {"k1": "v1"}
for url in urls:
    t = threading.Thread(target=requests.post, args=(url,), kwargs={'json': data, 'headers': headers})
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

But at the end I got this error `TypeError: post() got multiple values for argument 'json'`. So what is the appropriate way to call post request and to pass url, json and headers in threading lyb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set up your `threading.Thread` correctly. I advise wrapping up the target parameter in a function.

```
def post_requests(req):
    r=requests.post(req,json=data, headers=headers)
    print(r)
    return r
```

You don't need to include `kwargs`, then running your script with the following:

```
threads = []
for url in urls:
    t = threading.Thread(target=post_requests, args=(url,))
    
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Your output:

```
<Response [405]>
<Response [200]>
```

You might want to check why `"http://goggle.com"` returns `[405]`

Comment: Thank you for you answer tesla john I did it exactly the same way and it works. Sorry for very, very slow replay. The important is it works fine :)